# How do you apply a multi qubit gate to specific qubits in a multi qubit circuit?

Tags: quantum-computing

Let's say that you have a 6 qubit system and you want to apply a Hadamard gate to qubits 2 and 4.

How would you construct a matrix that did that, while leaving the state of the other qubits alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that the qubits were $0$ and $1$ (or $1$ and $2$, depending on your numbering scheme). You want to apply the Hadamard gate on the first two coordinates, and nothing – the identity – on the rest. This leads to a block diagonal matrix whose second block is the $4\times 4$ identity.

Now make the necessary arrangements for the qubits you're interesting it.

Comment: My question is specifically, what are the necessary arrangements when not using neighboring qubits? :p

Comment: You take the tensor product of your gate and the identity on the rest of the bits. I don't know what you mean by *arrangement*. In terms of matrices, this is just a block diagonal matrices with its rows and columns shuffled.

Comment: It turns out I didn't ask the question I intended to ask, due to incomplete understanding.  Sorry about that Yuval and thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yuval, I meant to ask about a multi qubit gate.  For instance, let's say you wanted to apply a controlled not to qubits 2 and 4, in a 6 qubit system.  I'd like to ask a new question for that, but the title is going to be the same as the title of this question so not sure.  Think I ought to delete this one??

Comment: @AlanWolfe You'll have to ask the moderators.

Comment: I just went ahead and asked a new one, in case you want some more points hehe.  http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48834/applying-a-multi-qubit-quantum-gate-to-specific-qubits